# jquery xml parsing not working

Tags: xml, jquery

I am trying to parse the xml but its not returning anything

here is the code jquery and xml code below. Is there something i am doing wrong?

```
<script language="javascript">

   /* $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "view_xml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) { parseXml(xml); }
      });
    });
    */
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "view_xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function(data,status) { parseXml(data.responseXML); }
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("inst:cView").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("type") + "<br />");
    /* output
    Disks
    Disks

    */
  });

 $(xml).find("inst:field").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("name") + "-");
    $("#output").append(": " + $(this).find("name").text() + "<br />");
    /* output
     TargetObjectClass -:Disk
     TargetObjectName -:DISK A1
     DisplayName -:DISK-Name
     MaxAvgDataRate KB/sec -:50.00 KB/sec
     MaxAvgQueueDepth -:50.00 
     ...
     ...

    */
  });
}
</script>
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <entry>
    ----
    ----
    <cView type="D1">
                    <field name="TargetObjectClass">Disk</field>
                    <field name="TargetObjectName">DISK A1</field>
                    <field name="DisplayName">DISK-Name</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgDataRate KB/sec">50.00 KB/sec</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgQueueDepth">50.00</field>
                </cView>
                <cView type="D2">
                    <field name="TargetObjectClass">Disk</field>
                    <field name="TargetObjectName">DISK B2</field>
                    <field name="DisplayName"> Disk-Name 2 </field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgDataRate KB/sec">60.00 KB/sec</field>
                    <field name="MaxAvgQueueDepth">60.00</field>
                </cView>


    ...
    </entry>
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried using 'xml' instead '$(xml)' ?

Comment: tried that didnt output anything

Comment: yes it valid xml i had left it out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "view_xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function(data,status) { parseXml(data.responseText); }
  });
});
```

**Edit regarding your xml tags :**

```
Using data.responseText
And <cView type="..."> instead of <inst:Cview type="..."> works like a charm.
The same for <field ...> instead <inst:field ...>.
```

Because ":" makes the selector search some "pseudo-element" and not a tag.

So, finally, **you just have to escape ':'**, like that :

```
$(xml).find("inst\\:cView")...
$(xml).find("inst\\:field")...
```

**Edit regarding your new XML**

To get the arborescence of data, use following :

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("cView").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("type") + "<br/>"); 
    $(xml).find("field").each(function()
    {
        $("#output").append($(this).attr("name") + " : ");
        $("#output").append($(this).text() + "<br/>");
    });
    $("#output").append("<hr/>"); 
  });
}
```

The content of each "field" is `$(this).text();`

Comment: I think that I've found the problem, please check my answer if it's right :-)

Comment: Any suggestion how i can retieve the inside value for example  <field name="MaxAvgQueueDepth">60.00</field> i cant seem to get the 60.00 out?